# Is it possible to take and transfer still pictures to a PC from a SONY HDR-AS100V camera?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I have bought a Sony HDR-AS100V camera and I would like to take capture still images from the camera, and transfer them (either via USB or WI-FI) to a PC preferably running Windows.

Sony has an API for this camera, however according to the table on [this](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/) page (and the documentation), it is not possible to transfer images. Is this really still the case?

The capture still images function has the following remark for this camera: "These cameras support only *actTakePicture*".

Reading through the documentation, this is the most obvious function to use for a still image. Why is this written as a remark?! I merely need a full HD RGB images sent to a PC once a minute approximately.

Firmware updates does not change this? The mini version of the camera has the capability to transfer images - but not the "larger" version.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`actTakePicture` is everything that you need to receive the taken picture. According to documentation it returns:

> Array of URLs of postview
>
> The postview is captured image data by camera. The postview image can
>   be used for storing it as the taken picture, and showing it to the
>   client display.

```
{
    "result": [
        [ "http:// ip:port/postview/postview.jpg" ]
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

After the picture is taken, you can use any method for HTTP GET the picture from provided URL.

---

**Special note (details)** from SDK documentation:

This API instructs the server side to shoot still image. When this API is called and the server starts
shooting still image, the camera status will change as follows. The camera status can be obtained by
"getEvent".

Camera status: "IDLE" -> "StillCapturing" -> "StillSaving" -> "IDLE"

Note that this sequence is the example of typical case.

The client should check the "getEvent" parameter ("cameraStatus") and check if it is "IDLE" before
calling this API. The camera needs to prepare for the next shot, therefore it may take time to start
next capturing after changing to "IDLE". The camera will start capturing as soon as possible.

In case of long exposure, the server will return "40403" error ("Still Capturing Not Finished") within
several tens of seconds. If status code "40403" is received, capturing is not completed. Use the
"awaitTakePicture" API to receive status on capture. If status code "40403" is received for
"awaitTakePicture" again, the client can call "awaitTakePicture" until the capture is done.

This API is only available when the shoot mode is "still".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, however this is what is stated in the documentation. My question (which apparently may need to be rephrased) is on why does the website say "These cameras support only actTakePicture" as a remark to the still images function.

Comment: My understanding is that they support only actTakePicture and not awaitTakePicture.